# Highcharts node-export-server in offline mode

Tags: highcharts

I use the solution : https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server to generate graphics on the backend. I have been using this library only on my local computer with windows to do some tests. And I decided to install it on a private Debian 10 server (the installation went well). But the problem is that when I want to generate a graph on my private server with this command line : highcharts-export-server --instr '{"title": {"text": "My Chart"}, "series": [{"data": [1, 2, 3]}]}' --type png, I get the following SSL errors:

> 139645463776896:error:25066067:DSO support routines:DLFCN_LOAD:could not load the shared library:dso_dlfcn.c:185:filename(libssl_conf.so): libssl_conf.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
> 139645463776896:error:25070067:DSO support routines:DSO_load:could not load the shared library:dso_lib.c:244:
> 139645463776896:error:0E07506E:configuration file routines:MODULE_LOAD_DSO:error loading dso:conf_mod.c:285:module=ssl_conf, path=ssl_conf
> 139645463776896:error:0E076071:configuration file routines:MODULE_RUN:unknown module name:conf_mod.c:222:module=ssl_conf

Therefore I deduced that a third party service was called to convert the graph. And so after this error, I would like to see to manage everything on my own server and not go through a third party service. I could read that there is an offline export service available for Highchart.js on the client side but I could not find any documentation indicating an offline export service. Could someone explain me how to do a local side only export with node-export-server?

Thanking you in advance.

I tried to use to disabled fallbackToExportServer
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.fallbackToExportServer with this command line :

highcharts-export-server --instr '{"exporting":{"fallbackToExportServer": false}, "title": {"text": "My Chart"}, "series": [{"data": [1, 2, 3]}]}' --type png

But it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

[offline-exporting](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.fallbackToExportServer) is a module for the Highcharts library to export the chart directly on the client side using the browser in which the chart is displayed. It is an alternative to sending a query to a public export server (https://export.highcharts.com/) or a custom-modified one (node-export-server).

In summary, `fallbackToExportServer` is a property available for the Highcharts API, not for node-export-server.

As for the SSL error, these issues on GitHub may be helpful: https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server/issues/307

Comment: ok thanks, I will check that